# How to rename a file which is in MultiPartFile format in java

Tags: java

For MultiPartFile, it stores the full path and has mainly 2 function which retrieve original path and other one absolute path. Then how to rename it. Using getOriginalFilename() you can find the file name withhout path. And I don't want to change extension and want to see filename without extension

Comment: @Spara please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @piet.t What's wrong? The article also said if you want to save or document you can answer your own question? So, what is the problem?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your question - my comment was directed at Spara who didn't seem to know about self-answered questions.

Comment: I See. So @Spara downvoted? And how come I can't see who downvoted and you can see? Is it due to reputation?

Comment: Nobody can see who downvoted, there just was a comment by Spara that I replied to.

Comment: Spara has reputation of 2557 and in top 0.09% of this month. Then how come he/she downvote without explaining what's wrong. If you can't explain how will I know my mistake @Spara ??

Comment: Oh, Spara deleted the comment after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the name using getOriginalFilename() and you know in which directory you want to store. So, I am using regex to extract extension. Then rename file name without extension and then append with extension

```
String directoryName = "D://JSA//"; //where to store
File directory = new File(directoryName);
if (! directory.exists()) //if dir is not there and you store then it will not create dir and so on no file will be there
{
    System.out.println("Directory is not there");
    directory.mkdir();
    System.out.println("Created");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Directory is there");
}

String name = file.getOriginalFilename();
String fname="", ext="", totalname="";
System.out.println("\n\nFile name : " + name + "\n\n");
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".[a-zA-Z0-9]+");//find all matches where first char is '.' then alphanumeric
Matcher m1 = p.matcher(name);//it will store all matches but we want last match eg abc.def.jpg we need .jpg ext
while (m1.find()) 
{ 
   ext = m1.group();
} 
fname = name.substring(0, name.length()-(ext.length()));
System.out.println("Name : " + fname);
System.out.println("Ext  : " + ext);
totalname = fname;
if(ext != "")//if ext is there concat
    totalname += ext;
System.out.println("Full name  : " + totalname);

File convertFile  = new File("D://JSA//" + id + ext);//id store the name eg pic and ext=.jpg so pic.jpg
convertFile.createNewFile();
FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream(convertFile);
fout.write(file.getBytes());
fout.close();
```